# How to pass button title to multimedia filename Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass button label to the filename of my multimedia.
Unfortunately it's not working.

Idea is when I press button named "cat" it will play filename named "cat", "mp3"
If I press button with label "cow" it will play sound with filename "cow".

So I tried already different variant's but I can't make it work. If you guys have some ideas, please help.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func playAudio() {
        do {
            self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("buttonName", ofType: "mp3")!))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func playSound(sender: AnyObject) {
        let  buttonName = sender.currentTitle!
        playAudio()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.pathForResource(:String?,: String?)` method of `NSBundle` does not take a selector, but a `String`. Hence, in your case, you will always try to open `"buttonName.mp3"`, rather than the contents of some property called `buttonName`. Moreover, `playSound` in your function `playSound(..)` lives only locally in the scope of that function; and since you do not pass its value to `playAudio()`, the latter does now know of it. Finally, the `sender` for @IBAction is an `UIButton`, you're better of actually using type `UIButton` rather than `AnyObject`.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func playAudio(buttonName: String) {
        do {
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(buttonName, ofType: "mp3") ?? ""))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {
        if let buttonName = sender.currentTitle {
            playAudio(buttonName)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you should avoid using forced unwrapping of optionals (`!`) unless you know specifically that they will not be `nil`; I've used optional binding instead in the example above (`if let ...` in `playSound(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in Swift, but I don't think that dope LLVM can fix these for you:

- You initialized `buttonName` as local variable, and you didn't pass it to `playAudio()` (which does not accept parameters anyways), it's 100% not working to me.
- Since you didn't pass the local `buttonName` to `playAudio()` as a parameter, you can't get the button name within the function scope. Also, you use `"buttonName"`, which is a `String` object, not even a variable. There's no file called `buttonName.mp3` in your bundle, so nothing would happen (will always `print("Error")`).

Something like this should work: (Not tested, but should be similer)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func playAudio(buttonName: String!) {
        do {
            self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(buttonName, ofType: "mp3")!))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func playSound(sender: AnyObject) {
        let  buttonName = sender.currentTitle!
        playAudio(buttonName)
    }
}
```